# Find Users OAuth connected Apps via API or tables

Tags: api, external-app

I need to be able to find out what external apps users have installed through the API or a table.  In their User record there you can view a related list of records and **Revoke** them from there.

How can I access this information via API or data tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin I work with has just figured out to do this.

Under setup:

[image]

Once you are here, you can click on the actual number of users using the app:

[image]

And then you have it:
[image]